# How can we `Download media` from firebase url

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

- I am new on Android and I don't know how to download `media` from
  `firebase`
- In the `uploadFile` method I am uploading media in `FirebaseStorage` and after getting success response `downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` sends to `FirebaseDatabase`
- I am also getting `url` but not able to `download` media from `url`

---

```
   private void uploadFile(Uri uri) {
    StorageReference uploadStorageReference = mStorageReferenceMedia.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    final UploadTask uploadTask = uploadStorageReference.putFile(uri);
    showHorizontalProgressDialog("Uploading", "Please wait...");
    uploadTask
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Log.e("MainActivity"+"241>>>>", downloadUrl.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityChatView.this, "ulr>>"+downloadUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sendURL();

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(ActivityChatView.this, new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    int progress = (int) (100 * (float) taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                    Log.e("Progress>>", progress + "");
                    updateProgress(progress);
                }
            });
}
```

---

[image: Response after hit the url]

---

```
public class DownloadTask {

    private static final String TAG = "Download Task";
    private Context context;
    private Button buttonText;
    private String downloadUrl = "", downloadFileName = "";

    public DownloadTask(Context context, String downloadUrl) {
        this.context = context;
        this.buttonText = buttonText;
        this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;

        downloadFileName = downloadUrl.replace("", "");//Create file name by picking download file name from URL
        Log.e(TAG, downloadFileName);

        //Start Downloading Task
        new DownloadingTask().execute();
    }

    private class DownloadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        File apkStorage = null;
        File outputFile = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try {
                if (outputFile != null) {
                    buttonText.setEnabled(true);
                    Log.e("57","download"+"completed");
                } else {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("62","download again");
                        }
                    }, 3000);

                    Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("72,","download failed");
                //Change button text if exception occurs
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("80","download again");
                    }
                }, 3000);
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed with Exception - " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);//Create Download URl
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Open Url Connection
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");//Set Request Method to "GET" since we are grtting data
                c.connect();//connect the URL Connection

                //If Connection response is not OK then show Logs
                if (c.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Server returned HTTP " + c.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + c.getResponseMessage());

                }


                //Get File if SD card is present
                if (new CheckForSDCard().isSDCardPresent()) {

                    apkStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                                    + "downloadDirectory");
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Oops!! There is no SD Card.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //If File is not present create directory
                if (!apkStorage.exists()) {
                    apkStorage.mkdir();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Directory Created.");
                }

                outputFile = new File(apkStorage, downloadFileName);//Create Output file in Main File

                //Create New File if not present
                if (!outputFile.exists()) {
                    outputFile.createNewFile();
                    Log.e(TAG, "File Created");
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);//Get OutputStream for NewFile Location

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();//Get InputStream for connection

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//Set buffer type
                int len1 = 0;//init length
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);//Write new file
                }

                //Close all connection after doing task
                fos.close();
                is.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                //Read exception if something went wrong
                e.printStackTrace();
                outputFile = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Than AsyncTask and HttpURLConnection combination I would recommend DownloadManager** as its the proper way to do it and it can continue download from where it was cut off, from the docs

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running
>   HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
>   particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the
>   download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and
>   retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and
>   system reboots.

Please refer this [example](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/).
To further help you in debugging consider this

1) please make sure that the url is actually uploaded in the database by verifying it and give a proper name with extention as you are depending on this during download.
2) physically open the file location to see if the file was atleast created and use proper filename extensions like .mp3 or .txt for the file.
3) you are depending on the name you get from db is it proper with extentions,

Answer (score 0):

You should use **StorageReference** to [download file from *Firebase Storage*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files).

To download file from URL

```
// Create a storage reference from our app
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

// Create a reference to a file from a Google Cloud Storage URI
StorageReference gsReference = 
    storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg");

//Download file in Memory
StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg");

final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
islandRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new         
OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) for more details and other options to download file.

Read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) to upload files.